# Is there a method to check if a string/char exists in another string?

Tags: java, string

Is there a method in Java where you can get a sub-string from a string? Like for example, I have a:

```
string_a = "B1 B2 B4 B3"
```

Is there a way to check if the `string_b = "B3"` exists in the `string_a`? I'm doing a program where `string_a` can change its value but `string_b` is constant. I need to check if `string_a` has a `string_b`.

Comment: `string_A.contains(string_b)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `contains` it takes either char or string as an argument and returns true or false. So for your problem, you need:

```
string_a.contains(string_b)
```

Answer (score 7):

Check the Javadocs for answers to questions like this.

The method you want is [String.contains(CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence).). A String is a CharSequence, so you can pass in a String as the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called contains. So you would be doing:

```
bool result;
String stringOne = "test";
result = stringOne.contains("st"); // result is now true
```